# Using Azure DevOps task build the .Net core application that uses external Package Source

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Using Azure DevOps task, I am trying to build the .net core application that uses external Package Sources like mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="Public" value="https://microsofthealthoss.pkgs.visualstudio.com/FhirServer/_packaging/Public/nuget/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="local" value="./lib" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have the following tasks defined

```
        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: 'NuGet restore'
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'
            feedsToUse: config
            nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: "Restore dotnet packages"
          inputs:
            command: restore
            projects: "**/*.csproj"
            feedsToUse: 'config'
            nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: "Build with Development configuration"
          inputs:
            projects: "**/ProductX.HIS.WebApi/**/*.csproj"
            arguments: "--configuration Development"
```

It is throwing the following error

```
Build FAILED.

       "/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
       (Restore target) -> 
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.
         /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/FHIR-Converter-main/src/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter/Microsoft.Health.Fhir.Liquid.Converter.csproj : error NU1301: The local source '/home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/lib' doesn't exist.

    0 Warning(s)
    8 Error(s)
```

I have the **lib** folder in the Azure DevOps Repo as shown below

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does the command work locally for you? Your issue is your local source path has `Nuget` in it. The `./lib` value in your `NuGet.config` would need to be `../lib` to fix this but that could break the solution if you everything works locally.

Comment: It works locally on the windows laptop as well as in docker. Can I just restore the entire solution and build the solution instead of building the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following tasks to address this issue

```
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - task: CopyFiles@2
              inputs:
                SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/lib'
                Contents: '**'
                TargetFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/Nuget/lib'
                OverWrite: true
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              displayName: "Restore dotnet packages"
              inputs:
                command: restore
                projects: "**/*.csproj"
                feedsToUse: 'config'
                nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
            - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
              displayName: "Build with Development configuration"
              inputs:
                projects: "**/ProjectX.WebApi/**/*.csproj"
                arguments: "--configuration Development"
```